# How to calculate distance between two points in n dimensions with Java?

Tags: java, vector

I'd like to write a function that can calculate the Euclidean distance between two points, no matter how many coordinates the points have (assuming both points have the same number of coordinates)?

For two dimensions its of course

```
public static Double getDistance(Point2D p, Point2D ref) {
    double dXSquared = Math.pow(p.getX()-ref.getX(), 2);
    double dYSquared = Math.pow(p.getY()-ref.getY(), 2);
    return Double.valueOf(Math.sqrt(dXSquared + dYSquared));
}
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this without having to write workarounds to figure out how many coordinates a point has? Like direct vector operations as in numpy would be nice.

Comment: How do you represent the n-dimensional point?

Comment: Essentially, unless you are using a vector library that gives you a method to calculate the L-2 norm, you do have to use the number of elements in the vector. (And even if the library gives you this method, it's doing what you need to do internally).

Comment: @AndyTurner Good question, I'm actually thinking about something like a `Point` interface and `Point2D` or `Point3D` can implement it. However I'm unsure what's a meaningful API for a point.

Comment: [NDArray](https://javadoc.io/doc/ai.djl/api/latest/ai/djl/ndarray/NDArray.html) is supposed to be an analog to some numpy stuff as far as n-dimensional arrays are concerned, but euclidean distance I couldn't see at a first glance, though it might be easy to express it.